Microsoft Graph API - Pagination to get more than 500 members
I'm trying to extract the users of an azure group, I use first a function ''GetToken'' to get select the group from Azure and the token, then I use this function to get the users:
let
    Source = (GroupID as text)=>
let    
    token= GetToken() ,
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://graph.microsoft.com",
     [
         RelativePath = "v1.0/groups/" & GroupID & "/members?$top=500",
         Headers=[Authorization="Bearer " &  token]
     ])),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each ([Name] <> "@odata.nextLink")),
    Value = #"Filtered Rows"{1}[Value],
    #"Converted to Table1" =  Table.FromList(Value, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" =  Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table1", "Column1", {"@odata.type", "id", "businessPhones", "displayName", "givenName", "jobTitle", "mail", "mobilePhone", "officeLocation", "preferredLanguage", "surname", "userPrincipalName"}, {"Column1.@odata.type", "Column1.id", "Column1.businessPhones", "Column1.displayName", "Column1.givenName", "Column1.jobTitle", "Column1.mail", "Column1.mobilePhone", "Column1.officeLocation", "Column1.preferredLanguage", "Column1.surname", "Column1.userPrincipalName"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Column1",{"Column1.@odata.type", "Column1.businessPhones", "Column1.jobTitle", "Column1.mobilePhone", "Column1.officeLocation", "Column1.preferredLanguage", "Column1.givenName", "Column1.surname", "Column1.userPrincipalName"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Column1.displayName", "Analytics Full Name"}, {"Column1.mail", "Analytics Login"}, {"Column1.id", "User id"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
in
    Source

The problem is that the maximum I can get is only 500 users ( For now I want to extract about 1300 users )
I checked some documentation and found out that  with the $top parametre, power bi is supposed to give the rest of the users using the odatalink. I tried to do it with a recursive function :
let
    GetMembersRecursive = (url as text, token as text) =>
    let
        response = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, [Headers=[Authorization="Bearer " & token]])),
        members = response[value],
        nextLink = Record.Field(response, "@odata.nextLink", null),
        result = 
            if nextLink <> null then 
                List.Combine({members, GetMembersRecursive(nextLink, token)}) 
            else 
                members
    in
        result
in
    GetMembersRecursive

Then the new code to get the users :
let
    GetUsersForADGroup = (GroupID as text) =>
    let
        token = GetToken(),
        url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/" & GroupID & "/members?$top=500",
        members = GetMembersRecursive(url, token),

        #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(members, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
        #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "displayName", "mail"}, {"User id", "Analytics Full Name", "Analytics Login"})
    in
        #"Expanded Column1"
in
    GetUsersForADGroup

But unfortunately it's not working. Someone told me to use the Table.GenerateByPage() but it's also not working.
I still get errors. Does anyone ever used pagination with the $top parameter? Or does anyone have another lead?  is there another way to do it without the recursive function?

Try to insert @ before recursive call of the function:
List.Combine({members, @GetMembersRecursive(nextLink, token)})

